# php preg_split or explode. Not removing the character

Tags: php, regex, explode, preg-split

I have been trying several ways to solve my issue and have found a poor work-around, but I would like to know if there is something else out there.
I have a string of several sub-strings which are separated by commas. I can split this up into an array using preg_split or explode. BUT some of the sub-strings also contain commas that I do not want to split into separate array members. My work around is to include a full stop at the end of every string and then tell explode to split only on ".,".
Example string:

```
$string = "Henry the horse, Billy the donkey, Harry the mule, George, the hippo";
```

Work-around

```
$string = "Henry the horse., Billy the donkey., Harry the mule., George, the hippo.";
$list = explode('.,',$string);
```

I can't for the life of me think of any way to tell the program that the comma after George is not the end of the sub-string.
Another (related) issue is that I would like to split the string at the commas BUT include the commas in the array members.

```
==> Henry the horse,
==> Billy the donkey,
==> Harry the mule,
==> George, the hippo,
```

My idea for this is simply to add them again after. Is there a simpler way?
In other words is there a way of splitting at a delimiter BUT keeping the delimiter in the array members?

Comment: If you don't know the logic on how to decide whether a comma is part of the substring or a delimiter, then it will be impossible to tell PHP to do it. So what is the logic?

Comment: Any feed-back on my comment, or on the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that each substring must start with a capital. Then this would do it:

```
$string = "Henry the horse, Billy the donkey, Harry the mule, George, the hippo";

preg_match_all("~[A-Z].*?(?:$|,)(?!\s*[a-z])~", $string, $result);
```

`$result[0]` will contain the following output:

```
[
    "Henry the horse,"
    "Billy the donkey,"
    "Harry the mule,"
    "George, the hippo"
]
```

Comment: Yes, the string originates from an array in which each member starts with a capital letter, so this should do the trick. I didn't know that preg_match_all returned an array! I am going to have to get my head around the regex (tutorial time). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookarounds or `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. Either usw `,(?! the)` or `, the(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,` with `preg_split()`.

*Tapping on my mobile*

Answer (score 0):

`preg_split` supports the flag `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`. See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

The delimiter needs to be in parentheses:

```
php > var_dump(preg_split('/(, )/', 'Henry the horse, Billy the donkey,
Harry the mule, George, the hippo', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));

array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "Henry the horse"
  [1]=>
  string(2) ", "
  [2]=>
  string(16) "Billy the donkey"
  [3]=>
  string(2) ", "
  [4]=>
  string(14) "Harry the mule"
  [5]=>
  string(2) ", "
  [6]=>
  string(6) "George"
  [7]=>
  string(2) ", "
  [8]=>
  string(9) "the hippo"
}
```